# How to install PHP cURL on IIS?

Tags: iis, php, curl

How do I go about installing PHP cURL on IIS? I have copied the php_curl.dll file into the PHP extensions folder, what else do I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to register the modul in the php.ini.

Look for:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

And check for correct extension dir:

```
extension_dir = "c:/path to php/ext"
```

Comment: I've added extension=php_curl.dll to php.ini, and checked the directory is correct, but i'm still having no luck. Should cURL then appear on a phpinfo() once i've done those steps?

Comment: yes it does appear. You have to restart the web server processes (depending on gateway cgi/fastcgi/iis-extension).