# HowTo install cURL on ISS 7, PHP5 and Win Server 03

Tags: iis, iis-7, curl

my question is in the title allready "How to install cURL on a windows server 2003 machine with ISS 7.0 and PHP 5?".

I try to read HowTos in the internet but don't get any word what todo, I have too less experience with php and command line things...

So I hope somebody here understands what to do and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen and the research I've done, the easiest way would be to boost a curling sheet (presumably folded or disassembled) into LEO, and then utilize a manned mission to retrieve the sheet and bring it to the ISS for assembly and installation.  However, insofar as I'm aware, there are no plans to provide a suitable module for incorporation of such a playing surface into the ISS's living space, so you'd be reduced to playing during EVA, which doesn't seem likely to go over well with the mission managers.

Why do you ask?

*For more information*:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curling
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS

Comment: I mean not curling, I mean http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: Ah.  In that case, check http://serverfault.com/questions/141091/how-to-install-php-curl-on-iis .